# Button in Java eclipse

Tags: java, android

I made a program that computes the geometric mean and my program is already working but i have some sort of errors. Whenever i click the btnCalculate with an empty input in my inputValues my program stops working. how am I going to deal with this error? Thanks:)

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView inputValues = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_input);
    final TextView txtTotalNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_totalNumber);
    final TextView GeoMean= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_GeoMean);

    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {
            String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));//this is the inputed values in the editText using split method
            txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));//calculate the number of inputs
            double[] convertedValues = new double[values.length];

            double product1 =1.0;
            double product=1.0;

            for(int a = 0; a < convertedValues.length; a++){
               convertedValues[a] =Integer.parseInt(values[a]);
               //product *=convertedValues[a];
            }

            double geoMean = Math.pow(product, product1/convertedValues.length);
            GeoMean.setText(Double.toString(geoMean));

        }

    });

    Button btnclear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnclear);
    btnclear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         inputValues.setText("");
         txtTotalNum.setText("");
         GeoMean.setText("");


        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Post your logcat.

Comment: You mean you get an "App stopped unexpectely ... " on the Android screen? Then you should have the Stack Trace in the Logcat. What is it saying? Can you give us that?

Comment: mostly it is NULL pointer exception. check the value is not null.. or post logcat error

Comment: check for null condition inside ur onClick.If it not null then execute otherwise skip the block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting errors because your code is trying to split on empty strings or null and then accessing values[] that really have no index at all. Just check if the string fetched by the EditText has a length>0.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View agr0) {
        String fetchedValues = ( inputValues.getText().toString());
        if(fetchedValues.length>0)
        {
          String []values = fetchedValues.split(",");
          txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));//calculate the number of inputs
         double[] convertedValues = new double[values.length];

         double product1 =1.0;
         double product=1.0;

         for(int a = 0; a < convertedValues.length; a++){
            convertedValues[a] =Integer.parseInt(values[a]);
            //product *=convertedValues[a];
         }

         double geoMean = Math.pow(product, product1/convertedValues.length);
          GeoMean.setText(Double.toString(geoMean));
       }
       else
       {
          //alert the user that the field is empty
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {
            String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));//this is the inputed values in the editText using split method
if(values !=NULL){
            txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));//calculate the number of inputs
            double[] convertedValues = new double[values.length];

            double product1 =1.0;
            double product=1.0;

            for(int a = 0; a < convertedValues.length; a++){
               convertedValues[a] =Integer.parseInt(values[a]);
               //product *=convertedValues[a];
            }

            double geoMean = Math.pow(product, product1/convertedValues.length);
            GeoMean.setText(Double.toString(geoMean));
}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {
            if(inputValues.getText().toString().length()>0){
            String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));//this is the inputed values in the editText using split method
            txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));//calculate the number of inputs
            double[] convertedValues = new double[values.length];

            double product1 =1.0;
            double product=1.0;

            for(int a = 0; a < convertedValues.length; a++){
               convertedValues[a] =Integer.parseInt(values[a]);
               //product *=convertedValues[a];
            }

            double geoMean = Math.pow(product, product1/convertedValues.length);
            GeoMean.setText(Double.toString(geoMean));
          }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops at

```
 convertedValues[a] =Integer.parseInt(values[a]);
```

because for an empty input the split array has no values, so its length is 0. And when you try to access `values[0]`you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Just check if the input is emty, before splitting it.

```
if(!inputValues.getText().toString().equals("")){
    ... // do your stuff
} else {
  // show a message
}
```